# popt Library usage

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to get my head around how the popt library functions for parsing command line arguments to a program. For instance, what is the purpose of the structure poptOptions and how does poptGetCoontext() work?

I know that there is a bit to cover, so does anyone have any advice on where I can get more info on this library?

A brief of what I am trying to do:

Currently an application is set up to accept arguments in the format

`bin/app_name string1 string2 string3 < file_name`

What I intend to do is

`bin/app_name string1 string2 string3 string4 < file_name1`

and depending on string4, the file (file_name1) will need to be formatted.

Answer (score 3):

In any Linux system, install popt developer package 
e.g., Fedora:

```
sudo dnf install popt-dev
```

In Debian and Ubuntu it probably is:

```
sudo apt-get install libpopt-dev
```

after a successful installation do:

```
man popt.3
```

or

```
man 3 popt
```

I believe the manual and library are extensive enough. If they aren't for you or you feel out of luck, try to download **rpm** [source code](http://rpm5.org/) as it relies heavily in this library for command line processing.

*I hope this was useful.*